# Eloquent queries work separately but not together in a subquery

Tags: php, eloquent

I'm trying to fetch some data with a subquery using Eloquent but `dd`ing returns nothing. Separately, this

```
    $discountArticles = $discountTableItemIdIn
            ->where('recipient_type', '=', 'article')
            ->toArray();
```

or this

```
    $discountArticles = $discountTableItemIdIn
            ->where('recipient_id', '=', $articleId)
            ->toArray();
```

work fine.

However when I try something like this, it fails (or rather, returns nothing):

```
    $discountArticles = $discountTableItemIdIn->where(function ($subQuery) {
        $subQuery
            ->where('recipient_type', '=', 'article')
            ->where('recipient_id', '=', $articleId);
    })->toArray();
```

I know I can do separate queries on the same collection and do an `array_merge` but I'd like to get this way working instead. Not sure what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `$discountTableItemIdIn` is a collection of the entire table? That means you're gonna need a different function, as the `->where()` logic on a collection is different from how it functions on a builder (eloquent) instance.

Try using `filter()`:

```
$discountArticles = $discountTableItemIdIn->filter(function ($item) use($articleId) {
    return $item->recipient_type == "article" && $item->recipient_id == $articleId;
})->toArray();
```

What this will do is filter your `$discountTableItemIdIn` collection for records that have a type of `article` and a `recipient_id` of whatever `$articleId` contains, return a new collection and convert that to an array.

Just a note, this is quite inefficient; you should try to avoid loading the whole table into a collection and just query the table directly using the subquery logic in your question.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to see if this work. As for your note, the problem is that there are many foreach iterations in my cron, and each queries different tables (thousands of queries) with unique IDs of different objects. The cron took 8 hours originally.. this way it'll kill the server with inefficiency, but at least it should be faster. Perhaps you have another suggestion to this approach? Im fairly new to Eloquent and PHP in general.

Comment: Ah; I see, that makes sense. From experience, I've found that leveraging the heavy lifting to SQL is always performant-plus over having Collections handle it, but I can't say I've done anything to the scale you're describing. 8 hours is an ungodly long time for a script to run, and if this approach performs better than that, then it should be ok. Just be aware of the differences between Eloquent and Collection methods and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you. Your method worked btw, (or at least, it's a great starting point!). Cheers